# Importa y Exportar en React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de importar y exportar en React.js? Necesito ayuda con esto ya que he estado teniendo problemas desde que empecé con React y me gustaría que alguien con experiencia en React me lo explique. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y podría terminar cerrada por ello. Haz clic en [edit] y acótala a un problema particular o específico. ¿Qué problema tienes con `import` y `export`? Te comento que eso no tiene nada que ver con React, es la implementación del lenguaje (Javascript). React es sólo una librería escrita sobre ese lenguaje. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé si será el caso, pero cuando se usa React (u otras librerías js) directamente desde CDN es decir, importándolas directamente con etiquetas , no podemos usar los imports como tal, sinonque debemos cargar los distintos ficheros con etiquetas script igualmente.

Para usar, por ejemplo un useState, en vez de hacer el import con:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

Pues lo que hacemos es directamente llamarlo a partir del objeto React que, al ser cargado por medio de la etiqueta script en el documento, ya lo tenemos referenciado. Por ejemplo, podríamos hacer un componente funcional con un estado del siguiente modo:

```
function miComponente(props){

    const [dato, setDato] = React.useState();

    return (
        <div className="miClase">{dato}</div>
    );
}
```

Es decir, en vez de usar directamente **useState** (que sería como lo haríamos si lo importamos) pues usamos **React.useState** y listo.

No sé si será esto a lo que te refieres, pero puedes hacer uso de React de este modo sin tener que usar los imports. Si haces un archivo js con tus componentes, asegúrate de cargarlo en el documento (no es neceario que sea en el head) y podrás usarlos.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: gracias la verdad es que soy nuevo en react ya que vengo de backend con .NET C# asi que tengo poca experiencia con react pero gracias me ayudo